# resize model popup according to screen resolution in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

My application is in asp.net 4.0 and I am using AJAX model pop up extender in my application for showing details of xyz company on click of company name in grid view. So while showing company details in model popup when I am looking same page on big screen the position of pop up window is changed.

Can any body tell me how can I set position of model pop up on page according to the scree resolution.

Following is the code where I tried to set width and height dynamically but it did not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function fnCalculate()
   {
     alert(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);
     w = screen.width * 0.8 ;
     h = screen.height * 0.8 ;
     document.getElementById("#content").style.width = w;
     document.getElementById("#content").style.height = h;
     document.getElementById("#content").style.left = w*h;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: WHat is "AJAX model pop up"?  Are you talking AJAX Control Toolkit, or your own script, or a JQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier to set up the height and width as a percentage. And mey be setting `top` and `left`.

Whatever the screensize it is the `pop-up` gona occupy the whatever the percentage you applied.

```
#content{ position: absolute;height:50%;width:50%;}
```